# Connect a second display while dedicated GPU is disabled

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, cpu, gpu

I have a laptop running Windows 11 beta, with an i5 8th gen CPU and a GTX 1050-Ti dedicated GPU. Normally when I connect a second display via the HDMI port, the dedicated GPU starts running and takes care of the second display.

Now for some reason I have had to disable my GPU drivers, and now plugging in the display into the HDMI simply does nothing. Is it possible to run the second display via the integrated Intel graphics, i.e. CPU alone? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: I also have an i5 8th gen and according to Intel Control Panel, the cpu can support 3 monitors. In W10, I don't think my GPU was used for external display. Don't know about W11. Also, on any Linux distro, with my dGPU, I can run an external monitor with iGPU

Comment: What make and model laptop is it ? While the integrated GPU in the i5 can handle multiple displays, the manufacturer may have chosen to run the HDMI out straight from the 1050 for some reason.

Comment: @Silbee it's an Acer Predator Helios 300, 3 year old.